# service to service communication through Resttemplate with Spring cloud(Oauth 2)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon, spring-cloud-security

Hi I am trying to call a spring boot service from a different service through Rest-template. i am using consul as service discovery 
now
Service1-->rest-->Service2

I dont want this communication through Zuul service1 should be able to call service2 directly but ribbon should discover the second service through consul. every thing is working fine but when i try to call service1 to service2 i am getting below exception at service1

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:41) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.getAccessToken(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:125) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa4e9ed0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.captureUrlTemplate(RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.java:33) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:620) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:609) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$edba1d43.getForObject(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at hello.PCNApplication.available(PCNApplication.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.execute(MethodExecutionAction.java:116) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.executeWithArgs(MethodExecutionAction.java:93) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.execute(MethodExecutionAction.java:78) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand$1.execute(GenericCommand.java:47) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.AbstractHystrixCommand.process(AbstractHystrixCommand.java:146) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand.run(GenericCommand.java:44) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:293) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:289) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

**Below is my code**

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RibbonClient(name = "service1", configuration = SayHelloConfiguration.class)
@EnableResourceServer
public class Service1Application extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }   
  @RequestMapping(value = "/someHome")
  @HystrixCommand
  public String available() {

     String response=restTemplate.getForObject("https://Service2/service2Home", String.class); 
      return " Welcome to service1 Notification home Page :-"+response;

  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Service1Application.class, args);
  }

 @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health").permitAll().and() 
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").anonymous().and()
      .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
      .httpBasic().and()
      .addFilterAfter(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
  }
}
```

**NOTE: every thing is on https**

Comment: We found that this because of hystrix. Can anybody help me to solve this with hystrix ????

Comment: did you solved this somehow?

Comment: No now we are not using Oauth in that way but you can try it by Feign client(Instead of using RestTemplate) we were able to achieve same with that.....

Comment: I'm currently using feign client, but that client is invoked from within separate threadpool and of course request attributes are not propagated. Are you calling feign client from current thread or from "custom thread"?

Comment: But I think it should work by using oauth2resttemplate

Comment: no we are not doing it by our self but if u are using hystrix some time it does

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your HystricCommand to be executed in the same thread, it will be able to see session-scoped OAuth2 authentication details needed for OAuth2RestTemplate:

```
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties={
    @HystrixProperty(name = execution.isolation.strategy, value = "SEMAPHORE")
})
```

Beware, you are losing timeout capabilities of HystrixCommands (see Note under https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#semaphores).